# Buying the right kind of Laptop RAM

Tags: laptop, memory

I am looking to add an additional 4GB of RAM to my Laptop to take it to a total of 8GB. However, I want help to figure out the right kind to buy.

I am told that the RAM's have to be identical in some aspects like Latency, Voltage etc to work properly so need your help.

My laptop is Samsung NP300E5C-A02IN.

And this is what CPU-Z says about the existing RAM,

[image: CPU-Z screenshot with RAM details]

Comment: "try asking how to find out what suits your needs" – um, isn't this literally what OP is already asking in the 1st paragraph?

Comment: @nshunz Have you tried any RAM vendor sites such as Kingston?  Their tools are usually able to identify the needed module quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's DDR3
- You want 4 GB
- CPU-Z shows ~800 MHz, but DDR stands for **Double** Data Rate, so look for 1600 MHz
- CPU-Z shows that CL is 11, you can buy higher (ie. slower) but the current memory module will slow down to adjust
- It's a laptop, so look for SODIMM (laptop-format) sticks

Regarding voltage, [Crucial's recommendation tool](https://eu.crucial.com/eur/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Samsung/np300e5c) offers only 1.35V modules. It's a safe choice anyway, those modules will also work with 1.5 V.

Comment: Thanks. What is the voltage I need? Some models say 1.5 and some other 1.35? And what does Unbuffered mean?

Comment: @nshunz See my update